# ¿Cómo simular la apertura del teclado en React Native?

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, jest, jestjs

Hoy me encontraba haciendo algunas pruebas para un proyecto que estoy desarrollando. Quería crear un hook personalizado que me permitiera saber cuando el **teclado** del dispositivo estaba **abierto** o **cerrado**. Esto me serviría para ajustar el diseño de la interfaz según el estado del teclado. Para comprobar la funcionalidad del hook, necesitaba simular la apertura y el cierre del teclado. Sin embargo, no encontré ninguna opción para hacerlo de forma sencilla. Busqué en la documentación oficial y en varios foros, pero no hallé ninguna solución.

Intenté lo siguiente pero no funcionó:

```
    test('should return true if the keyboard is open', () => {
        let isOpenKeyboard
        const Component = () => {
            isOpenKeyboard = useKeyboardStatus()
            return <View>{isOpenKeyboard}</View>
        }
        render(<Component />)
        Keyboard.emit('keyboardDidShow')
        expect(isOpenKeyboard).toBeTruthy()
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Se veía prometedor, pero aún así no funcionaba.
Seguí buscando e intentando de diferentes formas, hasta que decidí leer el código de React Native y descubrí algo que puede que les sea útil.

Si desean emitir un evento creado con addListener, en casi todos los casos los podrán emitir usando `DeviceEventEmitter`, cómo su nombre indica, es para los eventos emitidos por el dispositivo.

**Así resolví mi problema**

```
DeviceEventEmitter.emit('keyboardDidShow')
```

Bastante más sencillo de lo que esperaba.

El uso es muy simple, solamente colocan el nombre del evento dentro de `DeviceEventEmitter.emit()`

```
DeviceEventEmitter.emit('nombreDelEvento')
```

Espero esto les sea de ayuda si se llegan a topar con el mismo problema o alguno similar.
Sin más recuerden que esto debería de ser usado solamente para hacer testing.